# Add XMonad to SDDM

Tags: x11, xmonad, sddm

I have installed arch and KDE.

Now I want to test XMonad :

- I build XMonad with Stack (because for some import I need the source)
- I create the desktop file in `/usr/share/xsessions/` with the right permission
- Reboot
- Chose XMonad in the login session and login
- Here I see a black screen and the script redirect me to the login screen :/

How can I add xmonad to my login session and have it work?

Permission

```
▲ lsa /usr/share/xsessions/
total 28K
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K May  1 18:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 427 root root  16K May  1 17:34 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.0K Apr  2 16:59 plasma.desktop
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  145 May  1 18:47 xmonad.desktop
```

xmonad.desktop

```
 ▲ cat /usr/share/xsessions/xmonad.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=XSession
Name=Xmonad
Comment=Lightweight X11 tiled window manager written in Haskell
Exec=xmonad
Icon=xmonad
Encoding=UTF-8
```

Other informations

```
 ▲ loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID        
Id=4
User=1000
Name=a2n
Timestamp=Sun 2022-05-01 18:48:58 CEST
TimestampMonotonic=42270986
VTNr=1
Seat=seat0
Display=:0
Remote=no
Service=sddm
Desktop=KDE
Scope=session-4.scope
Leader=901
Audit=4
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=0
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=0
LockedHint=no
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your PATH? `xmonad` needs to be on PATH to execute it like this, and it does not read from `$HOME/.bashrc`.

It is likely better to set xmonad's absolute path there.

(In case this is not the culprit, do you see errors like `xmonad.errors`?)